# Trace and log values of a variable with GDB

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I am not an experienced programmer but I recently have to check C code translated from Matlab, in order to ensure that with the same data set, C and Matlab are giving the identical results.

Watches are what I am able to use until now but that requires me to sit in front of the screen and watch the values of a variable change at each loop. Is there a way to trace and log the values of a variable into a .txt file so that I can plot it later to compare with the results from Matlab?

I have already tried to write the values into some .txt file with 'fwrite' but there is not the ideal solution as I have to do that in the C code that I want to check.  Embarrassed  I am currently reading about tracepoint of gdb and will try to use that but I am still unsure if that is what I need. If you have some tips about what else I try.

I´m using Windows 7 and work with CodeBlocks.

Thanks!
Christina

Comment: not used so much but i think this link can help you http://betterexplained.com/articles/debugging-with-gdb/

Comment: thanks! I´ll have a look.

Comment: welcome tell me if you find the solution

Comment: I suggest you should have both C and Matlab programs produce identical output files, then compare the resulting file with the diff command. Make sense?

Comment: @koodawg: I cannot compare the resulting files, I need to check intermediate results and I have a lot of values to observe. It's not that easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [breakpoint command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) to run when your watchpoint hits; have it log and execute a `continue` command to let the program keep running.